# Getting error while trying to install testNG from eclipse.

Tags: testng-eclipse

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.committers, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse/updatesites/6.11.0.201703011520/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar.
Read timed out

I have tried every solution that was available on google...Nothing worked. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

if you still have the installation issue, i guess there might be some firewall/network settings impacts that.
as a workaround, you can download the zipped update-site to you local, and install from the archive file.
see the list of zipped update-site: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse#update-sites